# Raphael JS Drag Path and maintain it in paper

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm new in Raphael JS and I test something about it.
I have to create a path and drag it.

Currently no problems.

My real problem is that I have to limit the move into the paper. 
My path must be constraint to move into my raphael paper.

```
(function() {
  var trans_x;
  var trans_y;
  var w = 300;
  var h = 300;

  var paper = Raphael('holder', w, h);
  var rectPath = paper.path("M0, 0L0, 90L90, 90L90, 0Z");
  rectPath.attr({
    fill: "green",
    cursor: "move"
  });

  var bBox = rectPath.getBBox();

  var startPath = function() {
      this.ox = this.attr("x");
      this.oy = this.attr("y");
    },
    movePath = function(dx, dy) {

      trans_x = dx - this.ox;
      trans_y = dy - this.oy;

      this.translate(trans_x, trans_y);

      this.ox = dx;
      this.oy = dy;

    },
    upPath = function() {};


  rectPath.drag(movePath, startPath, upPath);

})();
```

Here is my basic code in Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Drzep/7s8rxhat/4/

I tryed a lot of thing with math.min and math.max but nothing works for path. 
I have found how to do this with a raphael circle and rect, but not with a path.

Comment: You can use setviewBox property.

Comment: If you can do this with a circle or rect already, you should be able to use the getBBox() method on any element like a path, to get its x1,x2,y1,y2 points to compare against. Just run getBBox() and look at the output.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was tryed to use getBbox before but I found incoherent result (I think). Can you told me if the x and y result of the Bbox are normal here ? (Console.log) http://jsfiddle.net/Drzep/7s8rxhat/5/

Comment: here there my update : http://jsfiddle.net/Drzep/7s8rxhat/6/ I used  the getBBox to have the height, width x and y but my limit is not configure as well as I want ... If someone can help me I really don't understant the big difference between a shape and a Path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rewrote your code a little simpler,

I think you were messing with variable bBox so I removed it:

```
var nowX;
var nowY;
var paper = Raphael(0,0,300,300);
var rect = paper.rect(100, 100, 30, 30).attr({ fill: "blue", cursor: "move" });
var rectPath = paper.path("M0, 0L0, 90L90, 90L90, 0Z").attr({ fill: "green", cursor: "move", stroke: "#fff" });
function start() {
  this.ox = this.getBBox().x;
  this.oy = this.getBBox().y;
};
function move(dx, dy) {
  nowX = Math.min((paper.width - this.getBBox().width), this.ox + dx);
  nowY = Math.min((paper.height - this.getBBox().height), this.oy + dy);
  nowX = Math.max(0, nowX);
  nowY = Math.max(0, nowY);
  if (this.type == "rect") {
    this.attr({ x: nowX, y: nowY });
  }
  else {
    this.transform("T" + nowX + "," + nowY);
  }
};
function up() {
};
rect.drag(move, start, up);
rectPath.drag(move, start, up);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crockz/ttfy22fq/

Comment: Thanks Crockz. This is perferct. It is very clear now. I understand why it doesn't work before. I think I was looking for a solution too complicated using Bbox. Thanks a lot.